# LaunchRequest for Alexa skill keeps failing: There was a problem with the requested skill's response

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Alexa is unable to launch my alexa skill. When I test it by saying "Open Bigger Brain" or "Launch Bigger Brain", Alexa says "There was a problem with the requested skill's response". I have tried everything I could to fix this issue, checked the interaction model (JSON), the function code, but it just is not working. Any propositions to fix this?

This is my Python function code to handle LaunchRequest:

```
import logging
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils
from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractRequestHandler, AbstractExceptionHandler
from ask_sdk_core.utils import is_intent_name
from ask_sdk_model import Response
from ask_sdk_model.ui import SimpleCard

shouldEndRequest = False

to create SkillBuilder instance and register the handlers
sb = SkillBuilder()

custom LaunchRequestHandler to handle the skill launch
class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
def can_handle(self, handler_input):
return is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)


def handle(self, handler_input):
speech_text = "Welcome to Bigger Brain, the interaction model that is cooler than Alexa. Let us chat. Ask me whatever you want."  

def handle(self, handler_input):
handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech_text).set_card(
SimpleCard("Bigger Brain", speech_text)).set_should_end_session(
False)
return handler_input.response_builder.response

sb.add_request_handler(LaunchRequestHandler())
```

This is JSON for LaunchRequest (only LaunchRequest shown here:)

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "bigger brain",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "LaunchRequest",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "Start Bigger Brain",
                        "Launch Bigger Brain",
                        "Open Bigger Brain",
                        "Begin Bigger Brain",
                        "Begin",
                        "Alexa launch Bigger Brain"
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: Can you please include the JSON response your skill is sending in this scenario?

You seem to have def handle(self, handler_input): defined twice above. Wondering if that's related.

Also, you don't need to define an intent for launch requests. This is covered out-of-the-box. Intents you define in your interaction model will show up in your skill with a request type of IntentRequest. Launch requests are of type LaunchRequest.

Answer (score 1):

A sample request JSON sent to your skill and the JSON it responds with would help confirm, but I suspect one problem is that you are defining the LaunchRequest in the interaction model. Only defines intents in there. LaunchRequest and all the ways it can be expressed come out-of-the-box. Please remove that intent from your interaction model, re-build and deploy your skill, then try again. If it's still failing, please include the request and response JSON examples.